# A box contains 5 red balls, 3 orange balls and 2 green balls. Two balls are selected at random. Answer the following questions for the cases where the

Tags: probability

A box contains 5 red balls, 3 orange balls and 2 green balls. Two balls are selected at random. Answer the following questions for the cases where the selection is with and without replacement.

(a) What is the cardinality of the sample space of this experiment?

(b) Let $X$ represent the number of orange balls selected. What are the possible values of $X$? Calculate $P(X=0)$.

I am confused. The sample space, could be the pairs $(w_i, r_j), (w_i, g_k)$, where $w_i, r_j$ and $g_k$ are the white, red and green balls, respectively (distinguishing balls of the same color).

Could you explain the exercise and recommend a book where I can study this.

Comment: There is no white ball. It should be orange? I would not assume that the balls are distinguishable other than by their color. As you are picking two balls, the sample space should be just different color combinations of two balls. But when you are finding probability, you would have to treat them as distinguishable.

Comment: I would have thought (a) could have several possible answers to "the sample space" with between $6$ and $100$ elements, which in some cases will be equally probable and in others not

Comment: To emphasize "*What is the cardinality of* **the** *sample space of this experiment*"  This question is very poorly phrased.  There is no singular choice as to a sample space for an experiment... there can be *many*.  We often prefer one sample space over another because of concerns of readability, convenience of organization, and/or ease of computability.  We often prefer sample spaces who contain equiprobable outcomes so we can use counting techniques to calculate probabilities.

Comment: If the sample space were merely the possible values of $X$... $\{0,1,2,3\}$, those four outcomes are not equally likely.  While this choice of sample space is helpful because it is small and well organized... it is not very useful because calculations are frustrating.  On the other hand the sample space being $\{(r_1,r_1),(r_1,r_2),\dots,(r_1,g_2),(r_2,r_1),\dots\}$ containing each pair of balls drawn in sequence with order mattering... this sample space is much larger and there would need to be some thought (*albeit simple*) put in as to what value $X$ would take for each particular outcome

Comment: It is worth pointing out that although the balls may not have originally been labeled in the problem, it is worth *imagining* what would happen if they *were* precisely so that we can work in these equiprobable sample spaces we like so much so we can use counting techniques to calculate probabilities.  For instance, $\Pr(X=0)=\dfrac{7\cdot 6}{10\cdot 9}$ for the case of drawing without replacement... there being $7$ ways to pick the first non-orange ball and $6$ ways to pick a second non-orange ball given a first selection, and so on...

Comment: @Gabriela: I added an observation in my solution that says that although there may be different models to a problem, the relevant information is in the distribution of random variables. In may answer, this relates to the random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ that coin the number of orange balls. They are different random variables (functions) since they are defined in different domains. But their distributions are the same.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I understand. Thank you very much for your reply and input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably two balls are chosen without replacement, that is two balls are taken out from a bucket that has 5 reds, 3 oranges, and 2 greens. There is a little ambiguity as to what the sample space for this experiment should be.

- Some may think of combinations of colors as follows: $\Omega_1=\{\{r\}, \{r,o\}, \{r,g\},\{o\},\{o,g\},\{g\}\}$ which has $6$ elements.  Here $\{r\}$ means the the two balls drown were red, and similar interpretations for $\{o\}$, and $\{g\}$. The set $\{r,o\}$ for example, says that one ball was red and another ball was orange.
- Others may think of the experiment as drawing one ball first, keeping it, and then drawing a second ball from the bucket (that now has one less ball). In this case, the sample my be the color combination in the order they were drawn: $\Omega_2=\{(r,r), (r, o), (r, g), (o, r), (o, o), (o, g), (g, r), (g, o), (g, g)\}$ which has $9$ elements.

There may be other possibilities. Now, depending on how you define the sample space, the number of orange balls selected $X$ would take different forms.

- For $\Omega_1$ for example
  $X_1:\Omega_1\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is defined as
  $$\begin{matrix}
  X_1(\{r\})&=&X_1(\{r,g\})&=&X_1(\{g\})&=0\\
  X_1(\{r,o\}&=&X_1(\{o,g\})& & &=1\\
  X_1(\{o\})& & & & &=2
  \end{matrix}$$
- For $\Omega_2$, $X_2:\Omega_2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is
  $$ X_2(a, b)=\mathbb{1}(a=o)+\mathbb{1}(b=o)$$

Now there comes the issue of estimating probabilities. The assumption of the experiment is that two balls are drawn (without replacement) from the bucket described above. That has the meaning that, if all balls were labeled to make them distinguishable (not by color but by label) then each of the $\binom{10}{2}=45$ possible selections of unordered sets of size $2$ have the same probability of being chosen. Alternatively, each of the $10\cdot 9=90$ possible ordered pairs have the same probability of being selected.

Let us consider now experiment with $\Omega_1$ as the sample space.
The probability of interest for your problem is
$$P[X_1=0]=P[\{\{r\},\{r,g\},\{g\}\}]=P[\{r\}]+P[\{r,g\}]+P[\{g\}]$$
The probability of drawing two red balls is
$$ P[\{r\}]=\frac{\binom{5}{2}}{\binom{10}{2}}=\frac{10}{45}$$
This is because there are $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to choose two red balls out of $5$ read balls.

The probability of drawing one read and one green ball is
$$P[\{r,g\}]=\frac{\binom{5}{1} \binom{2}{1}}{\binom{10}{2}}=\frac{10}{45}$$
This is because there are $\binom{5}{1} \cdot \binom{2}{1}$ ways to select one red ball (out of 5) and one green ball (out of 2).

The probability of drawing two green balls is
$$P[\{g\}]=\frac{\binom{2}{2}}{\binom{10}{2}}=\frac{1}{45}$$
This is because there is $\binom{2}{2}$ ways to select two green balls out of two.

Putting things together
$$P[X_1=0]=\frac{10}{45}+\frac{10}{45}+\frac{1}{45}=\frac{21}{45}$$

Alternatively,
$$\begin{align}P[X_1=0]&=1-P[X_1>0]=1-P[\{\{o\},\{o,g\},\{o,r\}]\\
&=1-(P[\{o\}]+P[\{o,r\}]+P[\{o,g\}])\end{align}$$
The probability of choosing two orange balls is
$$P[\{o\}]=\frac{\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{10}{2}}=\frac{3}{45}$$
The probability of choosing one red and one orange ball is
$$P[\{o,r\}]=\frac{\binom{3}{2} \binom{5}{1}}{\binom{10}{2}}=\frac{15}{45}$$
The probability of choosing one green and one orange ball is
$$P[\{o,g\}]=\frac{\binom{3}{2} \binom{2}{1}}{\binom{10}{2}}=\frac{6}{45}$$
Putting things together gives
$$P[X_1=0]=1-\frac{24}{45}=\frac{21}{25}$$

---

Try to see of you can get the estimate using the model $\Omega_2$ and $X_2$. Notice that
$$\{X_2=0\}=\{(r,r),(r, g),(g, r), (g, g)\}$$
and so,
$$P[X_2=0]=P[\{(r,r)\}]+P[\{(r, g),(g, r)\}]+ P[\{(g, g)\}]$$
Then
$$P[\{(r,r)\}]=\frac{5\cdot 4}{10\cdot 9}=\frac{20}{90}$$
$$\begin{align}
P[\{(r, g),(g, r)\}]&=P[\{(r, g)\}]+ P[\{(g, r)\}]=\frac{5\cdot 2}{10\cdot 9}+\frac{2\cdot 5}{10\cdot 9}=\frac{20}{90}
\end{align}$$
$$P[\{(g, g)\}]=\frac{2\cdot 1}{10\cdot 9}=\frac{2}{90}$$

Putting things together
$$P[X_2=0]=\frac{42}{90}=\frac{21}{45}$$

You ay try computing the alternative way
$$P[X_2=0]=1-P[X_2>0]=1-P[\{(o, o),(r, o), (o, r),(o, g), (g, o)\}]$$

---

**Edit:** One important observation is the fact that even though $X_1$ and $X_2$ are different (they are functions defined in different domains) they do satisfy the following
$$P[X_1=a]=P[X_2=a],\qquad a\in\{0,1,2\}$$
In the language of probability theory, this means that $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same distribution (or they are equal in distribution).
This is an good instance of something that happens in applications of Probability and Statistics: One may have different models (probability spaces)$(\Omega_1,\mathscr{F}_1,P_1)$ and $(\Omega_2\mathscr{F}_2,P_2)$, and random variables (measurable functions) $X_j:(\Omega_j,\mathscr{F}_j)\rightarrow(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ with $P[X_1\in A]=P[X_2\in A]$ for all $A\in\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$. The importance then is not necessarily in the model, but in the distribution of a random variable of interest.

Comment: My teacher says this is wrong. I don't understand it. She says that the cardinality of the sample space (when there is replacement) is 100. I commented that it is only possible if you label the balls, but the problem does not say that this is so; she told me that this holds from the sentence "contains 5 red balls" and that if I was doing it the way you presented it is because I have an ignorance of counting techniques. I don't know what to do. I proposed the sample space $\{RN, NR, RV, VR, VR, NV, VN, VN, RR, NN, VV\}$. Apparently you have no objection to this one, well, you didn't answer me.

Comment: See Hnery's comment above. There are several models for this problem. Your teacher a model were the sample space is $100$. She is using replacement. In my solution, I assumed there is no replacement since in your posting it is not indicated that balls are drawn with replacement. I will add the replacement case in a few minutes.

Comment: That's what I was telling my teacher, but she wouldn't listen to me.

Comment: w=With replacement, after labeling the balls (not necessarily by color), there are $10^2=100$ possible ways to choose any 2 balls.
The probability of choosing no balls of orange color is given by $\frac{7\cdot 7}{10\cdot 10}=\frac{49}{100}$